# Unable to parse &amp; data from XML using XML Factory Instance parser

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, ampersand

I have an XML which I need to parse using XMLInputFactory(java.xml.stream).
XML is of this type:

```
<SACL>
<Criteria>Dinner</Criteria>
<Value> Rice & amp ;(without spaces) Beverage </Value>
</SACL>
```

I am parsing this using XML Factory Reader in JAVA and my code is:

```
if(xmlEvent.asStartElement().getName().getLocalPart().equals("Value"){
      xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();
      value = xmlEvent.asCharacters().getData().trim();  //Issue is in the if bracket only
}
```

(`xmlEventReader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLEventReader(new FileInputStream(file.getPath())); //using java.xml.stream.XMLEventReader`

But it is parsing the data like this only "Rice" (missing & Beverage)
Expected Output : Rice & Beverage

Can someone suggest what is the issue with "& amp ;"(without spaces) and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've worked on a project that did XML parsing recently, so I know almost exactly what's happening here: the parser sees `&amp;` as a separate event (`XMLStreamConstants.ENTITY_REFERENCE`).

Try setting property `XMLInputFactory.IS_REPLACING_ENTITY_REFERENCES` to `true` in your XML parser's options. If the parser is properly implemented, the entity is replaced and made part of the text.

Keep in mind that the parser is allowed to split it into multiple characters events, especially if you have large pieces of text. Setting property `XMLInputFactory.IS_COALESCING` to `true` should prevent that.

Comment: Another option is to create a `StringBuilder` on encountering `isCharacters()` or `getEventType() == XMLStreamConstants.ENTITY_REFERENCE` for collecting the corresponding characters into it including the manual de-escaped literals (then they're converted back to regular plain-text). I'm assuming you're not just in a hard-coded fashion access a single next `nextEvent()`, but do have a loop which gathers/collects text nodes until an element start or end (or document end or no `hasNext()` or other) is encountered.

Comment: Thanks a lot, setting property XMLInputFactory.IS_COALESCING to true worked for me and have fixed the issue.